# Seaborn no spacing on sides in regression plot

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm using seaborn to draw regression plots using the code below:

```
plt.clf()

x = pd.Series(data=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], name="X axis")
y = pd.Series(data=[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16], name="Y axis")

sns.set(style="whitegrid", rc={"lines.linewidth": 2.0, "grid.linewidth": 1.5})
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(width, height))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.tick_params(labelsize=20)
ax.set_title("My plot", pad=40, fontsize=30, fontweight='bold')
ax.set_xlabel(x.name, fontsize=25, fontweight='bold')
ax.set_ylabel(y.name, fontsize=25, fontweight='bold')
set_spines(2, 'black', ax)


sns.regplot(x=x, y=y, scatter=True, x_ci="sd", marker="+", ci=None, ax=ax, scatter_kws={'s': 800})

plot_file_path = standard_path + name + "_regression_plot.png"
fig.savefig(plot_file_path)
plt.close(fig)
```

However, the plot comes out like this (figure below), and the points on each end are at the very edge of each side of the plot. How can I keep some spacing so I can see better where the points hit the line at x=1 and x=8?

[image: Figure 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply added the range of x-axis with `ax.xlim(0,9)`.

```
ax = sns.regplot(x=x, y=y, scatter=True, x_ci="sd", marker="+", ci=None, ax=ax, scatter_kws={'s': 800})
ax.set_xlim(0,9)
```

[image]